# Force Open Lua Console or Run Lua Console Automatically on Startup

Tags: lua, console, listener, wireshark

I'm new to Wireshark & Lua and I have a question that I can't seem to find the answer to by reading around online

Is there a way to open the Wireshark Lua console window on start up? Or even automatically open dialogs created by listeners on start up? I was hoping there were some commands or capability that would allow me to open (not just create) dialogs from within a script.

I've read about the exploit for the console in versions 1.6 and earlier, but I'm running 1.6.8 and I'd rather not use something that could potentially cause Wireshark to be unstable.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the bottom of C:\Program Files\Wireshark\console.lua. Before the final "end", add:

```
run_console()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an advanced option in the preferences dialog:

1. Open `Preferences` from the `Edit` menu
2. Navigate to `Advanced`
3. Filter for `console`
4. Change the value for `gui.console_open` to `ALWAYS`